# Clarification in reference variable downcasting in java

Tags: java

Below is the sample code

```
class Animal {
    void makeNoise() {System.out.println("generic noise"); }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    void makeNoise() {System.out.println("bark"); }
    void playDead() { System.out.println("roll over"); }
}

class DogTest {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Animal animal = new Animal();
        Dog d = (Dog) animal; 
        d.makeNoise();
    }
}
```

Above code compiles well but when i try to run it, i get

> java.lang.ClassCastException

My assumption is it should print "generic noise" because at run time it should invoke actual Animal object makeNoise() method without giving any exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All answers here are technically correct. But I want to explain this from an other point of view.

First off, you have defined one `Animal` and one `Dog`. So far everything is fine. The problem comes when you (within `DogTest`) create an `Animal` and cast ti as `Dog`. Why? Not every `Animal` is a `Dog`. I mean, an `Animal` can be a `Bird`, a `Cat`, an `Elephant`... These `Animal`s do not "bark". Said that, you do can cast a `Dog` as an Animal because all `Dog`s are `Animal`s.

I hope I have clarified a bit your mind :)

Answer (score 4):

You can't cast an arbitrary `Animal` instance to a `Dog` instance, unless the instance you are casting is actually a `Dog` or a sub-class of `Dog`.

It would make more sense for the `Animal` class to be abstract, since an actual Animal that can be instantiated should be a specific Animal, such as `Dog`, `Cat`, etc...

Answer (score 3):

If you had:

```
Animal animal = new Dog();
Dog dog = (Dog) animal;
```

there would be no problem.

You need to understand the difference between **compile-time type** and **runtime type**. In the code snippet above, the compile-time time of `animal` is `Animal`, while the runtime type is `Dog`. This is why there's no problem *casting* to `Dog` (note that the actual casting happens at runtime).

In your code, however, the runtime type of `animal` is `Animal` (same as the compile-time type). This means that the `animal` will point to an object on the heap, that supports the features of an `Animal` (which is `makeNoise()`), but not the features of a `Dog` and that's why the `ClassCastException` happens.

Comment: It's more a matter of understanding the difference between the type of a variable and the actual object it points to.

Answer (score 0):

It won't print anything, because you won't reach the line with `d.makeNoise()`. The `java.lang.ClassCastException` is thrown in the earlier line, when you try to cast to `Dog` something, which is not `Dog`.

Still, without this line, you'll get the expected result: "generic noise".

Answer (score 0):

Best possible downcasting i can explain by re-writing your code as follows :-

```
public interface  Animal {
            public void show();
        }
        
        
        public abstract class Dog implements Animal {
            
            public void display(){
                System.out.println("Dog Called");
            }
        }
        
        public class Impl extends Dog{
        
            @Override
            public void show() {
                System.out.println("Impl Called");  
            }
        }
        
        
            class DogTest {
            public static void main(String [] args) {
               Animal a = new Impl();
               /**
                * child class's method tried to be accessed with the help of
                * parent class's object using downcasting of object
                * */
               ((Dog)a).display();
            }
    }
```

However real time such requirements can fulfilled without using explicit downcasting of objects instead with the help of Factory Design Pattern in  which we create object without exposing the creation logic to the client and refer to newly created object using a common interface.

Complete factory pattern can be pulled from [here](https://github.com/CodechefVaibhav/FactoryPattern)